# useEffect causes infinite loop

Tags: react-hooks

I search for SO posts 'useEffect causes infinite loop' and it looks like there are 36 other SO posts about this.  Most of the answers say to pass in a dependency array.  Something like this ...

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // do something and then do ...
    setMatch(match);
  },[match]);
```

Well here's what I have tried. All of the useEffect()'s I have tried still give me infinite loops.

I have tried this (no dependency array)

```
   useEffect(()=> {

        const url = 'http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/user/';
        const withCredentials = true;
        const method = 'get';
        axios.request({method, url, withCredentials}).then(response => {
            setAppUser({...appUser, ...response.data});
            setLoggedIn(true);
        })
    });
```

I have tried this (empty dependency array)

```
   useEffect(()=> {

        const url = 'http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/user/';
        const withCredentials = true;
        const method = 'get';
        axios.request({method, url, withCredentials}).then(response => {
            setAppUser({...appUser, ...response.data});
            setLoggedIn(true);
        })
    }, []);
```

I have tried this (putting `appUser` into the dependency array)

```
   useEffect(()=> {

        const url = 'http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/user/';
        const withCredentials = true;
        const method = 'get';
        axios.request({method, url, withCredentials}).then(response => {
            setAppUser({...appUser, ...response.data});
            setLoggedIn(true);
        })
    }, [appUser]);
```

Update: I tried this:

```
   useEffect(()=> {

        const url = 'http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/user/';
        const withCredentials = true;
        const method = 'get';
        axios.request({method, url, withCredentials}).then(response => {
            setAppUser((appUser) => ({...appUser, ...response.data}));
            setLoggedIn(true);
        })
    }, []);
```

All four of the above approaches result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thats is because you `setAppUser` and then the `useEffect` active again because the state changed and then it return in a loop.

Comment: @Omer so do I need `useEffect` at all? I need to contact my ReST API to see if the user is logged in or not.  If the user if logged in I need to redirect the user to their profile page.  If the user is not logged in I need to present them the login form.

Comment: I need to see the whole component, if you can make a fiddle it will be grate. I recommend you to use a service to do your api calls

Comment: I haven't used a service in react before. Do you know  where I can learn about react services?

Comment: services is just folder with js files that you call functions there if you need information, look at my first react app in github. (https://github.com/omergal99/react-bitCoin)